# Help identifying 2-pin 5-sided connector

Tags: identification, connector, power-connector

I'm trying to identify/match this 2-pin connector, would anyone happen to know what type it is / who makes it?

[image]

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [03062023](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/part-detail/crimp_housings/0003062023) from [Molex Wire to Wire](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/group/wire_to_wire_connectors) "Standard .062"+ and Standard .062" Pin and Socket Connector Systems" connector

Comment: So definitely too small, pitch is only 3.68 (mine's 6), but at least I have a lead on the type/manufacturer, thank you so much!

Comment: Pretty sure I found it, 03092022, has a 6.3mm pitch, so that looks right. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @MyFingerHertz